# Discordjs - message.member.roles.array() is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord

help

I get an error using array () and I don't know what to do

output:

```
if (validation(allowedRoles.roles, message.member.roles.array()) || message.member.id === owner)

ReferenceError: message.member.roles.array() is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

```js
if (validation(allowedRoles.roles, message.member.roles.cache.array()) || message.member.id === owner)
```